# express.static(path.join()) is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

```
const express=require('express');
const app=express();
const path=require('path')
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));

app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.status(200).render('main');
})
app.listen(5000,()=>{
    console.log("Serevr is running");
})
```

I created flappy bird game in javascript but when I comment out the   `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')))` this line code is work perfect but js file and the css file is not working in pug but when I use this line code server is not giving response means code stops in this line

Comment: What path to static assets are you using in your pug files?

Comment: Do you happen to have a `public/index.html` file?

Comment: Also, check your network tab of your devtools to ensure you are receiving any 404 erros, if you receive one then check the path is correct or not